# Shift an entire array to the by one position in php

Tags: php, arrays, key

For example:  I have an array that looks like this: `Array ( [0] => A [1] => B [2] => C [3] => D [4] => E [5] => F).` and etc..

I want to push the entire array by 1 to the right, so it looks like this: `( [0] => 0 [1] => A [2] => B [3] => C [4] => D [5] => E [6] => F).` and etc....

Edit: My bad. I didn't word my question properly. I'm hoping I don't confuse people trying to clarify.  I'd like to continue to push the array until the end of the array length.  For example $len is 7.  I'd like to perform an action on the array before iterating to the next position.   So it looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [6] => A).
```

My first attempt at this problem was to create a for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
  echo $chars[$i + 1];
  array_unshift($chars, 0);
}
```

My loop gives me 7 B's, which isn't what I want.

Is what I'm describing possible?

Comment: Do you want to also remove the last one? (Maybe you just forgot to add it to the question..)

Comment: No, I don't want to remove the last one. I just the values in the array to shift keys by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a loop. To shift the array the same amount of times as the array size, you can use [array_fill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) + [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$arr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'); $len = count($arr);
$tmp = array_fill(0, $len, 0);
$arr = array_merge($tmp, $arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
    [6] => A
    [7] => B
    [8] => C
    [9] => D
    [10] => E
    [11] => F
)
```

---

---

If you just need to shift once, use it like so:

```
$arr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
array_unshift($arr, 0); // adds 0 to the first item
// array_pop($arr); // you can remove the last one, if needed
```

Output (removing the last item):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => A
    [2] => B
    [3] => C
    [4] => D
    [5] => E
)
```

---

If you want **to add more than one** and they are different, you can also use array_merge:

```
$arr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
$arr = array_merge(array(0, 'foo', 'bar'), $arr);
// Output: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => foo [2] => bar [3] => A [4] => B [5] => C [6] => D [7] => E [8] => F )
```

Comment: is it possible to add '0's to the beginning of the array as the entire array shifts continues to the right by 1? That's why I surrounded the unshift with a loop.  Is that a question that I need to ask separately from this or edit my question?

Comment: @hnewbie What do you mean? Add as many zeros as there are items in the array?

Comment: @hnewbie eg: [A,B,C] would become [0,0,0,A,B,C]?

Answer (score 2):

Line

```
array_unshift($chars, 0);
```

is enough, without any loop:

```
$chars = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
array_unshift($chars, 0);
print_r($chars);  // [0, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Well I wanted to do a loop because I want continuously shift by 1 until it reaches the end of the array.